# How to integrate Facebook Login in Xamarin forms without Logging out

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.auth

I am planning to use Facebook for user authentication in Xamarin forms.

I read that Facebook doesn't allow refresh tokens, so how to keep the session alive unless the user explicitly signs out.

Comment: When the token is not valid anymore the user needs to go through the browser to get a new one(prompt the user to authenticate with Facebook again)

Comment: Seems to be bad user experience. Is there any other alternatives to allow user to sign up and login using Facebook. I wonder how so many other applications implement it without redirect to login page every hour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to tackle this. The login can be validated using Web Authenticator.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/web-authenticator?tabs=android#using-webauthenticator

Once user is validated, generate a custom JWT/oAuth token and use this token for the authorization instead. Delete it when user explicitly signs out, so it will again follow normal validation process.

Comment: Thanks for you sharing, please do not forget to accept your answer after two ways.